# Firebase Realtime Database ServerValue error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a program that displays a 'Start' button. Once the user clicks on this button, it will disappear and will:

- set `playerCount` to 1 (if `playerCount` does not exist)
- or increment `playerCount` by 1.

I am mainly having trouble incrementing `playerCount` by 1. I have been following the Firebase documentation for [Atomic server-side increments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments). The webpage and the 'Start' button both appear. However, after clicking the button and it disappears, I receive an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ServerValue') at [localhost url].js:37:65 {stack: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (re…ost:[localhost url].js:37:65", message: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ServerValue')"}`.

There is a similar post (but this is for FireBase Cloud) [firebase cloud function ServerValue increment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68240935/firebase-cloud-function-servervalue-increment-not-working). I have tried using `admin` instead of `firebase`, but I end up getting an `Error 404` error.

In case this helps, here is my `game.js`:

```
import * as firebase from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-app.js";
import { set, ref, getDatabase, child, get } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.1.3/firebase-database.js';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = {

    apiKey: "apiKey information",

    authDomain: "authDomain information",

    databaseURL: "databaseURL information",

    projectId: "projectId information",

    storageBucket: "storageBucket information",

    messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId information",

    appId: "appId information",

    measurementId: "measurementId information"

};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

function setPlayerCount() {
    const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
    get(child(dbRef, 'game/')).then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                const updates = {};
                updates['game/playerCount'] = firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1);
                database().ref().update(updates);
            }
            else {
                set(ref(database, 'game/'), {
                    playerCount: 1
                })
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        })
}

// Display Start Button and increment player count
let button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = "Start";
button.onclick = function () {
    setPlayerCount();
    button.style.display = "none";
}
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

and my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script defer type="module" src="game.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that firebase doesn't know which field to make the increment. AFAIK, You should use it in a set or update call.

Also, I think `ref(database,"game")` is a [collection reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference), and AFAIK, collections can't have fields and you can't store fields in a collection. So, you should probably use something like,

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "....."; 
const globalVarsRef = doc(database, 'game/globalVars');
setDoc(globalVarsRef, 
   { 
     playerCount: firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)
   }, { merge: true });
```

where "globalVars" is a document in "game" collection, and this document has playerCount field in it.